# Regex to convert URL in two parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to convert 2 parts of a URL, firstly strip away the middle section and then convert the start section to another string.

Are two part changes possible with Regex?

EXISTING

https://mybucketname.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myfilename.zip

REQUIRED

s3://mybucketname/myfilename.zip

The middle S3 url can change though, so it perhaps requires a wildcard (example urls: s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com, s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com)

Comment: in the required string, is *https* always gonna be replaced with *s3* or could it be replaced with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse it as a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and pull out the data you need:

```js
const url = new URL('https://mybucketname.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myfilename.zip')

const protocol = url.host.split('.')[1].split('-')[0]
const subdomain = url.host.split('.')[0]
const path = url.pathname
const result = protocol + '://' + subdomain + path

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like the following:

```js
const url = 'https://mybucketname.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myfilename.zip'

const match = url.match(/https:\/\/(.+)\.([a-z][0-9]).+\.amazonaws\.com\/(.+)/)


const result = match[2] + '://' + match[1] + '/' + match[3]

console.log(result)
```

You may need to adjust this depending on how the input changes. I'm assuming the `s3` bit is always a letter followed by a digit here.